# Is it possible to know when an IsolatedStorageFile was created without loading it?

Tags: windows-phone-7

we're caching these objects in xml files, and we wan't to ignore the cached file when 24+ have passed. I don't want to have to load the file to check if 24 hours have passed, so I'm wondering if there is a way to get the metadata of the file without loading it. Something like:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    DateTime dateTimeCreated = file.GetAttributes(this.CacheFileName)["DateTimeCreated"];
}
```

Let me know. Thanks!

Comment: How about a log file? (or you could make a list of Date + Name in your app settings)

Comment: That's possible too, but I want to go the simplest way for this task. If I don't find a better way I guess I'll use your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @lukas I actually used your suggestion, would you mind putting it as an answer to accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a log file? (or you could make a list of Date + Name in your app settings)

Comment: Thanks, ended up usin g the log file.

Answer (score 1):

There's no little phone icon next to the method, so it's likely not available, according to the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile(VS.95).aspx

Uggh...maybe keep a smaller file with only the last write time, so you know whether you need to load the big one or ignore it?  Or even some fancy datetime in the file name itself?

Comment: That sucks, I guess I'll really have to do that. Thanks =).

Comment: Yep.  Will likely put a yyyyMMddHHmmss UTC timestamp in the file name or directory myself, when I get to needing the same thing...unless the API is updated by then.

Answer (score 0):

I would use IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings to keep my filename and Metadata associated with that filename as a class instance.
I have used this in my WP7 apps and it works great. A good scenario for this is to check the file expiry for some caching implementation and if it is expired I can directly delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about what you could do that is simple and close to your needs...

If you're ok with the criteria being the current day, rather than the past 24 hours, then you could implement directories named with the date, say yyyymmdd format, then in your iso interface layer look for the file in the current day's directory.. if you don't find it, then there is no cache of it and you generate it.

You could implement house keeping to purge non current day directories at a convenient time.

This strategy will make your 24 hour time frame become more like 0-24 hour.. so an average of 12... skewed depending on the time of the day when you think your users are likely to use your app.

You could adjust the timeframe by being clever with the algorithm to generate the directory. For example you could make it produce a unique directory name every 2 days (for an average of 24 hour caching).

If IsolatedStorageFile.GetFileNames() was working with a filespec, you could encode the date into the latter part of the filename. Unfortunately it's still returning *.* regardless.